# Error when using function of imported package

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am running the follwing code:

```py
!pip install scikit-learn==0.24

import sklearn.metrics
mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(target_test.values, p)
```

but then get an error. What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this function from `sklearn.metrics` it is recommended to also
import only this function by using:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error

...
```

If you want to keep the syntax of your import as is, you have to call the function the following way:

```
mape = sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error(target_test.values, p)
```

If this is too long for you, you can import it and give it an own name:

```
import sklearn.metrics as skmetr

mape = skmetr.mean_absolute_percentage_error(target_test.values, p)
```